# Minimal client which supports message-level security over the channel interface

Tags: wcf, wcf-client, ws-security, x509certificate2, wshttpbinding

I'm trying to build a minimal client for a WCF service, using the WSHttpBinding with `SecurityMode: Message` over a direct channel interface.

My current code is very simple:

```
EndpointIdentity i = EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity(clientCertificate);
EndpointAddress a = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://myServerUrl"), i);
WSHttpBinding b= new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>(b, a);
channelFactory.Open();
IRequestChannel channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
channel.Open();
Message response = channel.Request(requestMessage);
```

The clientCertificate gets loaded properly.
However, afterwards, I'm unsure if I call every function the correct way.

The Fact is: The last line of the code snippet throws a `MessageSecurityException` with the content

> Client cannot determine the Service Principal Name based on the identity in the target address 'http://myServerUrl' for the purpose of SspiNegotiation/Kerberos. The target address identity must be a UPN identity (like acmedomain\alice) or SPN identity (like host/bobs-machine).

What could be the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The default ClientCredentialType seems to be Windows and that's why you're getting an error related to Sspi/Kerberos. You need to specify "Certificate" as credential type and also set the actual certificate in the client credentials container. Check out the Client section of this link for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733098.aspx